# adb device list is empty for one particular device

Tags: android, adb

I have two identical devices(not mobile phone) in which I am trying to update an apk file.
Device 1, I connect to my laptop using USB cable. I get a prompt to open the internal storage system of the device which is basically a SD card.
Now I run the adb devices command and I get the list of devices attached as "0123456789ABCDEF        device"

Then I disconnect the device 1 and connect device 2(Also reconnect the USB cable, adb kill-server and start it again). I get the same prompt to open the internal storage system. Then I run the adb devices and it the list is empty.

In both cases, I can see my devices correctly under the portable devices. I can not enable the USB debugging mode in the devices as the devices always brings an application after power up. So I can not reach settings screen.

Any help is appreciated. If you any questions to support, i would be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is because the vid of device2 is differnet from device1. You need to add the vid of device2 in adb_usb.ini file in C:/Users/your_pc_name/.android directory. You can get the vid from Computer-Device Management.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I could not locate any .ini file in mentioned folder. I have only adbkey, adbkey.android and analytics.settings files. And now I tried with the third device. I am able to get the device ID. But the second device is still can not access in adb shell.

Comment: ensure “Developer options” is ON in device2.

Comment: That is possible only if I could access the setting screen. When I power up the device it just brings a default application which makes sense. You do not have much option as you have in mobile or tab.